# Check if LocalTime is in range with Java?

Tags: java

Suppose I only have this API that the database have provided to do queries to find which records/entities in the database are within a specific `java.time.LocalTime` range

```java
EntityIterable entities = txn.find(entityType, propertyName, minValue, maxValue);
```

Where the minValue and maxValue are Java `Comparable`. A trivial example non-time use for this is for finding, for instance, price range:

```java
EntityIterable entities = txn.find("Book", "price", 10.00, 20.00);
```

Which will return all entries which has a price tag of `10.00` to `20.00`

Now, if I have a `LocalTimeRage` stored as property of an entity, as such

```java
Entity bookstore = txn.createEntity("Bookstore");
book.setProperty("openHours", range);
```

Where, `range` is a `LocalTimeRange` which is:

```java
class LocalTimeRange implements Comparable {

   private LocalTime upper;
   private LocalTime lower;

   @Override public int compareTo(@NotNull LocalTimeRange localTimeRange) {
    return 0;
   }

}
```

What should be the implementation of `LocalTimeRange` as such it would be possible to fit into a min-max query? What should be the implementation of `compareTo` method?

As such, this would be satisfied:

```java
EntityIterable bookstores = txn.find("Bookstore", "openHours", minLocalTimeRange, maxLocalTimeRange);
```

Comment: So you want to get all book stores whose open hours overlap with those ranges? Wouldn't you just provide _one_ range to compare with in that case?

Comment: @quarks Edited the post and now it's incorrect.

Comment: @George that is correct check my answer so you can review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to implement the `compareTo` to be able to compare with MIN-MAX using two `LocalTimeRage`:

```java
  @Override public int compareTo(@NotNull LocalTimeRange range) {
    if ((range.lower.isBefore(lower) && range.upper.isBefore(lower)) && (range.lower.isBefore(upper)
        && range.upper.isBefore(upper))) {
      return -1;
    } else if ((range.lower.isAfter(lower) && range.upper.isAfter(lower)) && (range.lower.isAfter(
        upper)
        && range.upper.isAfter(upper))) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Where you query it like this:

```java
EntityIterable bookstores = txn.find("Bookstore", "openHours", new LocalTimeRange(lower,lower), new LocalTimeRange(upper,upper));
```

A bit weird but it works.

Anyone is free to comment on this implementation.